# Can I look up in a car?

Tags: watch-dogs

I took the perk that lets me hack helicopters disrupting them momentarily. The only problem is that I can't seem to look up in a car. Having to exit my car in the middle of a chase to hack a helicopter doesn't really work...

Can I look up to the helicopter while driving my car?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about it but I think you can adjust the camera settings which enables it. On PC the default key is C.

Comment: Not entirely sure if this works, but just an observation I noticed whilst browsing the skills. There is a preview video of each skill, one of them is about increasing your focus time. In this video Aiden enters focus mode, maneuvers the camera round and up and hacks a helicopter. Maybe entering focus time gives more freedom of camera movement? Again, just an observation and not had time to test it yet.

Answer (score 2):

The vertical camera movement is very limited in vehicles, so it can be difficult to hack helicopters. The best way is to find a straight road and try to get far enough away from the helicopter so you can hack it without leaving the car.
It's also possible that if you stop, the helicopter will lower itself, but that's not really a good option in a car chase.

Answer (score 0):

You can't look straight up but you can look up and forward, or up and backwards. The helicopters don't typically hover directly above you if you stop for a second so it should be easy enough to get them from a farther off angle.